# Android: Accessing/Customizing Accounts View

Tags: android

I try to debug something in an open source app which created an account on my device. Like you have for your google account or whatever else.[image: screen]

It seems that this screen can be fully customized. I cannot find where in the code this screen can be changed. I am interesed in the menu, the list of accounts that you can tap on each to a new screen as well as the other screen elements.

Can someone give me a pointer where I can start?

Comment: account-authenticator=>android:accountPreferences ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly. There is a _service_ account authenticator. And what should I do there?

Comment: i was talking about authenticator.xml ...